# Create a second list by using for loop running thru all elements of a first list

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I'm fairly new to R and I want to clean up my code so that it is more dynamic and compact.
Basically I do two SQL outtakes and get two data frames "Cases" and "Debtors" that both have a field "case_id" that connects the case with the debtor and the field "product".
I create a list that partitions the Cases df by product:

`Cases_products <- split(Cases, list(Cases$product))`

and get a list containing 4 elements: product1, product2, product3 and product4.
Then I create a second list that partitions the "Debtors" into the corresponding products segments, also giving a list of 4 elements:

```
Debtors_products <- list(
   "product1" = merge(x = Debtors, y = Cases_products[["product1"]], by = "case_key", all.y = TRUE),
   "product2" = merge(x = Debtors, y = Cases_products[["product2"]], by = "case_key", all.y = TRUE),
   "product3" = merge(x = Debtors, y = Cases_products[["product3"]], by = "case_key", all.y = TRUE), 
   "product4" = merge(x = Debtors, y = Cases_products[["product4"]], by = "case_key", all.y = TRUE))
```

As you might note I want the names of the elements in my second list to be the same as the one in the first list that I am able to join/connect with.

The second list "Debtors_products" I feel has to be replaceable with a for loop, alas my attempts has been futile. I believe that my code below illustrates how I want to make my code more compact and dynamic but it is not working.

```
for (i in seq_along(Cases_product))

{Debtors_products <- list(Cases_product[i] = merge(x = Debtors, y = Cases_product[[i]], by = "case_key", all.y = TRUE))}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

/Regards

Comment: Prepare to do a head slap ... failing to index the LHS of an assignment operation.

Answer (score 1):

During assignment inside loop, index the element with desired value without `list` to avoid nested structure.

```r
# INITIZALIZE NAMED LIST
Debtors_products <- setNames(vector(mode="list", length=length(Cases_product)),
                             paste0("product", seq_along(Cases_product)))

# ITERATIVELY ASSIGN BY INDEX
for (i in seq_along(Cases_product)) {
   Debtors_products[[i]] <- merge(x=Debtors, y=Cases_product[[i]],
                                  by="case_key", all.y=TRUE))
}
```

However, use apply family to avoid the bookkeeping of assigning and indexing. Specifically, use `lapply` instead of `for` loop:

```r
Debtors_products <- lapply(Cases_products, function(df)
         merge(x=Debtors, y=df, by="case_key", all.y=TRUE)
)
```

Even better, because you are running `split` + `lapply`, streamline both calls with the rarely use `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`):

```r
Debtors_products <- by(Cases, Cases$product, FUN=function(df)
         merge(x=Debtors, y=df, by="case_key", all.y=TRUE)
)
```

---

And in SQL, run an outer join and import the larger set and split without iterative `merge`:

**SQL**

```sql
SELECT d.*, c.*        -- ADJUST TO AVOID NAME COLLISION
FROM Debtors d
RIGHT JOIN Cases c
  ON c.case_key = d.case_key
```

**R**

```r
Debtors_Products <- split(Large_SQL_Result, Large_SQL_Result$product)
```